# Overriding a method definition with a method from another class?

Tags: python, python-class

```
class test:
  def func(self):
    print(5)

class test1:
  def testing(self, t):
    t.func = self.another_func
  def another_func(self):
    print(6)

t = test()
t1 = test1()
t1.testing(t)
# now t.func() uses test1's another_func and prints 6
t.func()
```

This is a simple example I came up with for a larger problem I'm working on at work where this use case came up. I don't think I've seen function override of this sort done before, so while this can be done with seemingly the results that I'm seeking, should it be done? It feels hacky so I'm not sure if this is considered bad practice.

It also feels this makes readability more difficult because one might look at the original `func` definition and not know it was overriden

Comment: It may not be Pythonic but it works. So I don't see your problem. Further, your question is opinion-based and probably better suited for something like [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is it not possible to inherit from test and re-define the method that way?

Comment: @stressed Yeah I could, but it's a lot more work but probably the "better engineering" approach here

Comment: If this is truly for automated testing, then there are [modules for that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) which revert the code after the test is complete. If this isn't for testing and is some other form of monkey-patching, then use with **extreme** caution. I won't say "never do this", but I will say "almost never do this". 99.9% of the time, this is a really bad idea.

Comment: It's not really an *override*, rather, you are *shadowing the method* on an instance with a bound-method object on another instance.

Comment: "It also feels this makes readability more difficult because one might look at the original func definition and not know it was overriden" yes, this is definitely a problem with this approach. It is hard to suggest something different given that this is obviously a toy example